# C++ Builder Forms crashing

Tags: c++, c++builder

Form 1: (frmStart)

```
void __fastcall TfrmStart::btnRunClick(TObject *Sender)
{
    frmStart->Hide();
    Application->CreateForm(__classid(TfrmRunning), &frmRunning);
}
```

Form 2: (Running)

```
void __fastcall TfrmRunning::FormCreate(TObject *Sender)
{
      frmRunning->Show(); 
 //Here i do a lot of stuff to run my main program
}
```

The problem is that my first form loads and hides properly. When the second form loads no components are displayed just a GUI that looks like it has crashed/. When the program actually finisihes, the GUI returns to a normal  state.

Where did i go wrong?

Answer (score 2):

In the `OnCreate` event, the `frmRunning` variable has not been assigned yet, which is why the code is crashing.  Since you are already inside the class anyway, just use the method's `this` pointer instead:

```
void __fastcall TfrmRunning::FormCreate(TObject *Sender) 
{ 
      //frmRunning->Show();  
      this->Show();  
}
```

Or simply:

```
void __fastcall TfrmRunning::FormCreate(TObject *Sender) 
{ 
      //frmRunning->Show();  
      Show();  
}
```

Do the same thing in the `btnRunClick()` method - use the `this` pointer instead of the `frmStart` variable:

```
void __fastcall TfrmStart::btnRunClick(TObject *Sender) 
{ 
    //frmStart->Hide(); 
    this->Hide(); 
    ...
}
```

Or:

```
void __fastcall TfrmStart::btnRunClick(TObject *Sender) 
{ 
    //frmStart->Hide(); 
    Hide(); 
    ...
}
```

And lastly, you should be using the `new` operator instead of the `TApplication::CreateForm()` method, and do not call `Show()` method until the form is finished being initialized:

```
void __fastcall TfrmStart::btnRunClick(TObject *Sender)   
{   
    frmRunning = new TfrmRunning(Application);
    frmRunning->Show();   
    Hide();   
}   

__fastcall TfrmRunning::TfrmRunning(TComponent *Owner)   
    : TForm(Owner)
{   
   // initialize this Form as needed...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using FormCreate isn't the right place to set up your form. Use the c++ style constructor instead. 
I'd also probably call the Show method from somewhere else, such as another form's button handler, or the form's constructor. I would then use the OnShow Event to do the "lot of stuff"